# How do I pin a window that is opened by another command?

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, .desktop, tox

I frequently use Tox for communication, in particular the μTox client. I recently switched to Ubuntu from Debian, and am finding it a nice alternative, but I have one constant problem; because I often use μTox, I wish to pin it to the taskbar. I have written a custom `.desktop` entry and it shows up in the Unity Dash, but because of the way μTox is written, when I click on it in the Dash, it opens first the actual μTox process, but that then hides itself and opens a different window called `μTox (Alpha) (version: 0.8.1)`, meaning I am unable to pin it to the taskbar as it is a child process of the original `utox` process my `.desktop` file runs.

So how can I pin μTox to the taskbar?

Comment: Just for my understanding, you want to pin (minimize) an existing window to the *panel*, not to the launcher? Interesting, can be done. At the same time, if you minimize a μTox window, can't you reach it by right-click its icon?. Please let me know, I have to run, but if needed, will write a solution, because it's fun :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm What's the difference? (Sorry, I'm a Debian person).

Comment: @JacobVlijm Ah, OK. I meant the _launcher_.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Note that for me, μTox is 'installed' simply as a single file in `~/bin`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40096/discussion-between-george-gibson-and-jacob-vlijm).

Comment: Hi George, posted my answer. Please let me know if you manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while before I understood what you actually meant, but here is the answer:

#### Missing WM_CLASS

When you say:

*"when I click on it in the Dash, it opens first the actual μTox process, but that then hides itself and opens a different window called μTox (Alpha) (version: 0.8.1)"*

...it is a small misinterpretation of what is happening; there is no second process, but the launcher you created and the application do not "meet" each other in the Unity Launcher. In other words: the home-made launcher does not recognize the window, `μTox` is calling, as "his".

#### How to solve

You can simply solve it by including the `WM_CLASS` to your launcher, so it will correctly recognize the `μTox` -window:

```
StartupWMClass=utox
```

A simple launcher that worked fine here:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Some Tox
Exec=/home/jacob/Downloads/utox
Type=Application
StartupWMClass=utox
```

Of course you need to replace the path in the line `Exec=/home/jacob/Downloads/utox`

...But you might want to include an icon. If so add the line:

```
Icon=/path/to/toxicon.png
```

[image]

...and your issue should be solved :)

#### How to find the WM_CLASS?

- Open a terminal, type

  ```
  xprop WM_CLASS
  ```

  Press <kbd>Return</kbd> and click on the `μTox` window.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this appears to be just what I need. I've already done an icon, but did not know of the `StartupWMClass` option.